# Crear botones con jQuery y Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Si queremos **crear un botón en HTML**, es necesario un código similar a:

```
<input type="submit" value="Numero parrafos" id="num_parrafos" name="Numero Parrafos"/>
```

**¿Cómo se trasladaría el código a jQuery o a Javascript?** Para no tener la necesidad de modificar el código HTML. Simplemente crearlo desde un archivo externo .js que será llamado en el head del HTML entre las etiquetas `<script>...</script>`

**Código Javascript:** ¿es correcta la creación?

```
var boton = document.createElement("button");
boton.type = "button";
document.body.appendChild(boton);
```

¿Y si tenemos el botón dentro de una etiqueta global `<form>` al ser un formulario debería ser: "`document.body.form.appendChild(boton)`" o siempre hay que hacer referencia al body con "`document.body.appendChild(boton)`"?

Comment: Siendo el programador flojo que soy, haría una variable de string así `var boton = $('<input type="submit" value="Numero parrafos" id="num_parrafos" name="Numero Parrafos"/>)'` y daría append `$('body').append(boton)` esto claro solo contestaría a tu pregunta en específico sobre ese botón que pones de ejemplo, para hacer una creación ya serían más líneas de código dependiendo de cómo quieras crear tus botones.

Comment: Cuida porque el botón que estás creando es una etiqueta `<button` y en tu ejemplo tu botón es un `<input` que actúa de botón.

Comment: Yendo directo a tu pregunta, no siempre tienes que hacer referencia al body. Si usas vanilla JavaScript puedes seleccionar el elemento en en cual quieres agregar el botón mediante `getElementById` (entre otros) o `querySelector`. Con jQuery es más sencillo: `$('#elemento').append(boton)`.

Comment: Complementando el comentario de Gustavo igual puede usar $('#elemento').prepend(boton); te lo comento porque append lo agrega al final de los elementos que contenga el elemento al cual lo añades y prepend lo añade al principio de los elementos que contenga el elemento en cuestión, esto es útil saberlo de principio o al menos para mi es útil. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy facil mira, lo que haces es guardar tu boton en una variable asi:

```
var button = '<input type="submit" value="Numero parrafos" id="num_parrafos" name="Numero Parrafos"/>';
```

Despues lo que haces es que con **Jquery** insertas el boton al final del formulario con la funcion `append()` asi:

```
$('form').append(button);
```

Al final te va a quedar tu código asi:

```
var button = '<input type="submit" value="Numero parrafos" id="num_parrafos" name="Numero Parrafos"/>';
$('form').append(button);
```

Tambien puedes ponerle alguna **clase** o **ID** a tu form para referenciarlo de la siguiente forma:

`$('#formID').append(button);` o `$('.formClass').append(button);`

te dejo la documentación aqui:

Append Jquery: [Documentación](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

```
function crearElemento(elemento, identificador, clase, texto, ruta, valor) {
    item = document.createElement(elemento);
    if (identificador !=='__'){ item.id = identificador; }
    if (clase !=='__') { item.className = clase; }
    if (texto !=='__') { item.innerText = texto; }
    if (ruta !== '__') { item.dataset.cargarVista = ruta; }
    if (valor !== '__') { item.value = valor; }
    return item;
}
btn = crearElemento('button','num_parrafos','agrega tus clases','Numero parrafos','__','__');
body = document.body;
body.appendChild(btn);
```

Creo que este fragmento de código te podría servir. Puedes agregar mas atributos a la función si gustas.